# Criar Query eloquent em laravel para consultar que pegue a data maior da coluna e mostrar um veículo de cada

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso mostrar um veículo de cada(vehicle), que ordene por datatime maior('datetime_write), como faço para criar esta query com eloquent no laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que o nome do model eloquent seja Venda, você precisa ordenar pelo campo datetime_write em ordem decrescente e agrupar pelo vehicle_id

```
Venda::ordeyBy('datetime_write', 'desc')->groupBy('vehicle_id')->get();
```